# How to get rid of horses?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I started a stable and had to get specific horse types. I spawned way too many horses and now they're all just standing in the middle of the village I live in.  I don't know how to make them go away and I don't want to spend 8 hours killing them all.

Can I spawn a mob that will kill them for me?

Comment: Let's not create dupe chains, please.  Don't dupe to another dupe; just close it as a dupe of the original one.

Answer (score 3):

This command will kill all loaded horses.

```
/kill @e[type=horse]
```

This command will kill all horses within 10 blocks of you:

```
/kill @e[type=horse,r=10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Flood the area and drop a few blocks of TNT in the water.  Or, build straight up for height and fling a stack of splash potions of harming into the horse crowd below.  Or, pour a lava bucket in the middle of them.

All of these seem to solve your problem, and sound like a bit of fun.